# Why is this simple counter in simple Java app incrementing twice?

Tags: java

```
public class MyTestClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        char c;
        InputStreamReader reader = (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter chars:");
        OutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out);
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            counter++;
            c = (char) reader.read();
            outputStream.write(c);
            outputStream.flush();
            System.out.println(counter);
        } while (c != 'q');
    }
}
```

What I am trying is simple entering a character and then hitting enter..

What I will see is:

```
Enter chars:
a
a1

2
b
b3

4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is also a character, each time you hit enter you add a character. Use `nextLine()` for example, or filter the blank characters when you see it (test the character, ignore it if it is a blank character).

Answer (score 4):

When you hit Enter, your code receives a newline character. This is why you're seeing a blank line after `a1` and `b3`.

If you want to filter newlines out, check `c` for `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your "Enter" character is also considered a valid input character. You can use a condition filter for carriage return or decrement count value by 1 each time.